# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx'

Tags: npm-install, laravel-6

When i run "npm install && npm run dev"

i am getting this error

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx'

So what can i do to solve

Comment: it means you do not have the permission, either run as admin or install your laravel in a directory that you have access to.

Comment: this problem never has been occured before,,,,,

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after I've changed my computer user name. I didn't had a good idea to deal with the problem, but uninstalling `nodejs` and `npm` completely and deleting their environment variables. Then I reinstalled `nodejs` and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

1.Close your editor: Ensure all instances of your code editor are closed, as they might be locking certain files.

2.Clean the NPM cache: Run `npm cache clean --force` to clear any corrupted or locked cache files.

After that it will not showing the error.